# Database (sql ce) table is not created

Tags: windows-phone-7, sql-server-ce

I am creating helper app for my reference database. Here is code for db

```
public class DayNameDataContext : DataContext
{
    public static string DBConnectionString = "Data Source=isostore:/imieniny.sdf;";
    public ImieninyDataContext(string connectionString) : base(connectionString) { }
    public Table<DayName> DayNameTable;
}

[Table]
public class DayName
{
    [Column(DbType = "INT NOT NULL IDENTITY", IsDbGenerated = true,IsPrimaryKey = true, AutoSync = AutoSync.OnInsert)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Column(DbType = "DATETIME NOT NULL")]
    public DateTime Data { get; set; }

    [Column(DbType = "NVarChar(30) NOT NULL")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And in my app I have in page load event code

```
DayNameDataContext im = new DayNameDataContext(DayNameDataContext.DBConnectionString);
if (im.DatabaseExists() == false)
{
    im.CreateDatabase();
}
```

And when i copy db from isolated storage to desktop and open it in sql managament studio I don't have any tables created. I don't need any data bindings.

Comment: So your database is created but your table is not? You could try to uninstall your program and try to deploy it once more. For me that helped one time.

Answer (score 0):

I took a look at my Linq-to-SQL generated database code and i noticed one big difference between the generated code and yours.

My DataContext contains a Table property instead a Table variable maybe that's causing the problem.

And this extra lines too :

```
private static System.Data.Linq.Mapping.MappingSource mappingSource = new AttributeMappingSource();

    #region Extensibility Method Definitions
    partial void OnCreated();
    partial void InsertHeighscores(Heighscores instance);
    partial void UpdateHeighscores(Heighscores instance);
    partial void DeleteHeighscores(Heighscores instance);
    #endregion

        public HeighScoresDataContext(string connection) : 
                base(connection, mappingSource)
        {
            OnCreated();
        }
```

And my Table has some extra lines too a Constructor and Extensibility Method Definitions:

```
#region Extensibility Method Definitions
    partial void OnLoaded();
    partial void OnValidate(System.Data.Linq.ChangeAction action);
    partial void OnCreated();
    partial void OnIdChanging(int value);
    partial void OnIdChanged();
    partial void OnDifficultyChanging(int value);
    partial void OnDifficultyChanged();
    partial void OnFieldSizeChanging(int value);
    partial void OnFieldSizeChanged();
    partial void OnTimeChanging(int value);
    partial void OnTimeChanged();
    #endregion

        public Heighscores()
        {
            OnCreated();
        }
```

And try my suggestion in my comment try to uninstall your app and redeploy it for me it fixed once the problem.